# Comments in SP2013 getting issue in Next Page?

Tags: 2013, blog, comments

I am in SP2013,in the home page of the blog having posts,for every posts having comments, in the first page of comments will show up to 10, when I'm clicking on the next it was throwing error like

> "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904 Correlation
>   ID:3148cd9c-7071-50c1-c60d-b29ac0010a80"

I checked in logs based on correlation ID, I can find this error message

> "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion failed
>   when converting the nvarchar value '1#comments' to data type int.
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows) 
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean
>   setTimeout, Boolean& more)     at
>   S...  8546cd9c-a08c-a0da-b50a-f1bdd4208c22 11/18/2014
>   03:28:40.25*  w3wp.exe (0x1AA4)
>     0x2334  SharePoint Foundation           Database
>     d0d6    High        ...ystem.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.ExecuteQueryInternal(Boolean
>   retryfordeadlock)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.ExecuteQuery(Boolean
>   retryfordeadlock) 
>   ClientConnectionId:4a3111f5-76be-422b-b711-9b46aa1f0db0   8546cd9c-a08c-a0da-b50a-f1bdd4208c22"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem only seems to happen if you click on the comments at the bottom of the post.  If you click on the title of the post, it does not happen.

The problem seems to be that the URL associated with the number of comments has an anchor in it (#comments) and this is being passed into the sql query.

I've posted a question about this on [technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d972910b-48f7-4d16-b792-3a8c14e781dc/blog-post-comments-comments-anchor-causing-an-error-on-2nd-page-of-comments?forum=sharepointadmin).  Hopefully this can get corrected.